# How do you describe the sound of someone being dragged across the floor?

Tags: fiction, creative-writing, word-choice

So I'm writing this story and got stuck on the part where two of my main characters arrived at this house and they hear dragging but the problem is I don't know how to describe the dragging without telling.

To anyone who has ever been dragged across the floor or heard dragging before, is it alright if I ask how it felt or the sounds produced from it?

I just need an idea to practice more showing and not telling. If you know a site that does this, I'll be. Very greatful.

Comment: Why don't you have one friend drag another across the floor and record the sound? Then you can play it back as often as you need to figure out what it sounds like.

Comment: Asking what to write is off-topic here. Closing for now, but if you can [edit] this into a more answerable question (see our site [tour] for more on how to do that) we'll consider reopening.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum- that's a good idea. Now I'll just have to find someone willing to do so.

Answer (score 2):

How about, "the sound of something heavy -- perhaps a person -- being dragged across the floor"?

Answer (score 0):

Flesh scraping across wood, shoes scuffing the floorboards in a last, feeble protest.

Comment: Creates a very strong image a d imprints on the mind. I like it!